# How can I create spring integration flow read from kafka with queue limit process (parallel)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-kafka, spring-integration-dsl

I would like to create a stream that reads the kafka message asynchronously and uses a queue channel to accumulate a number of messages to process, and only at the end of processing these messages (50 messages for example) can it process another 50 or as it frees up space in that queue.
I tried using a flow that reads from kafka delegates to another flow with a QueueChannel with PollerMetadata (Pollers.fixedDelay(500).maxMessagesPerPoll(50)) but the poller uses a single thread to read the messages there, I can’t parallel processing the 50 messages, if I put an executor in the poller it will work like a normal executor and it will accumulate the messages and it will not hang at 50 until I have a new thread available for him to get another message from kafka.

The goal is to parallelize the processing of up to 50 kafka messages but that he only reads again in the kafka (consumer.pool) when this queue releases, but he is reading infinitely from the kafka and processing within the limit amount of the executor or poller, as can I achieve this goal using spring integration flow with kafka?

Only this configuration is enough for each consumer topic? the log always print the same thread: **[ntainer#0-1-C-1]** even I set 10 for concurrency

> Blockquote

```
> Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(consumerFactory,
> topic).configureListenerContainer { kafkaMessageListenerContainer ->  
> kafkaMessageListenerContainer.concurrency(concurrency)               
> kafkaMessageListenerContainer.ackMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.RECORD)
> }
>                 .errorChannel(IntegrationContextUtils.ERROR_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never use a queue channel or perform any async processing with Kafka. It's too difficult to keep track of the offsets within the topic/partitions. You will risk losing messages.

Instead, to increase concurrency, increase the number of partitions in the topic and set the listener container concurrency to get the number of consumers you need (e.g. 50).

You should generally have more partitions than consumers but you need at least as many because only one consumer in the group can consume from a partition.

Comment: Hello I need to process inventory updates for many tenants (there are 1,000 customers running simultaneously) and this update has an external service call that takes a certain amount of time, if I increase the number of partitions too much, kafka opens many files descriptor,

Comment: and imagine that I have for each seller per cycle 100 products with inventory update, with 1000 sellers to have an acceptable competition would have to have a topic with many partitions, and looking at Confluence's recommendations a topic with many partitions requires a very large monitoring of kafka, with 10 partitions I don't have enough parallelism to gain performance.
With that he had imagined not to block the receipt of messages and parallelize for a limited amount by a queue

Comment: Don't put code/config in comments; it's too hard to read. Edit the question instead. It is simply impractical to perform asynchronous processing of records from a single partition.

Comment: When the concurrency is set (your configuration looks correct) you should see n threads `...#0-0-C-1`, `...#0-1-C-1` - the fact that you cite `0-1-C-1` means you have at least two. If you have to go async on each consumer, perhaps Kafka is not the right choice for you. How do you plan on reliably manage the consumer offsets in sucn an environment?